# React PropTypes get the specified value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have been trying to get the proptype that I specified in my component.

In my component I have a static object propTypes:

```
 static propTypes = {
        width: PropTypes.number,
        disabled: PropTypes.bool,    
        // etc...   };
```

Now I have been wondering if I am able to get the PropTypes type I have specified. If I log the proptypes of my component, it shows says that the value of PropTypes is a function.

[image]

Is there a way to get the specified type out of there?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/247

Comment: No, there is no way but they should really expose this

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/issues/60

Comment: Ah thats too bad, I hope they will expose this soon. Thanks tho!

Comment: Can you please close this question then?

Answer (score 0):

Proptypes in react only throws a warning at run time. It doesn't suppprt any strict type checking.If you want to have a strict type checking , I would suggest to use Typescript instead of Javascript with React.It throws error at compile time which lets you know beforehand.

Comment: Mmhhh yes you are right. But I needed the proptypes in my application to show what type the input expects to show it next to it. Example: width (number). With number being my type